# PHP Loop returns duplicate results using CRON

Tags: php, wordpress, cron, html-email

I have a script that aims to remind users about events they've added to their planner on a website. The script works fine if I load it up in the browser and echo out the result, all of the events that should be there, are there.

However, if I put this code into a function that fires off with a CRON, I get the right number of events in the list, but they all have the information from the last event.

Any ideas why this may be?

Here's the code that runs the script below.

```
<?php $args = array(
        'role' => 'Subscriber',
        'meta_key' => 'planner-reminders',
        'meta_value' => '0',
        'meta_compare' => '==',
    ); ?>

    <?php $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args ); ?>

    <?php if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) : ?>


        <?php foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) : ?>
            <?php $matchedEvents = array(); ?>

            <?php $user_id = $user->ID; ?>

            <?php $planner = get_field('events', 'user_'.$user_id.''); ?>
            <?php $events = explode(" ", $planner); ?>



            <?php $plus = 0; ?>
            <?php foreach ( $events as $event ) : ?>


                <?php $args2 = array(
                    'post_type' => 'event',
                    'p' => $event
                ); ?>

                <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( $args2 ); ?>

                    <?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
                        <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

                            <?php if( have_rows('date') ): ?>
                                <?php $row = 0; ?>
                                <?php while ( have_rows('date') ) : the_row(); ?>
                                    <?php $row++; ?>
                                <?php endwhile; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php if( have_rows('date') ): ?>
                                <?php $count = 0; ?>
                                <?php while ( have_rows('date') ) : the_row(); ?>

                                    <?php
                                        $startDate = get_sub_field('start-date');
                                        $endDate = get_sub_field('end-date');
                                        $date = date('Ymd');
                                    ?>

                                    <?php if( $endDate < $date && $count === $row ) : ?>

                                        <?php break; ?>

                                    <?php elseif ( $endDate > $date  ) : ?>

                                        <?php if( $startDate <= $date ) : ?>

                                            <?php if ($count === $row) {
                                                break;
                                            } ?>

                                        <?php elseif ( $startDate < date('Ymd', strtotime('+7 day') ) ) : ?>

                                                <?php array_push( $matchedEvents, get_the_ID() ); ?>

                                            <?php if ($count === $row) {
                                                break;
                                            } ?>

                                        <?php endif; ?>

                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php $count++; ?>  
                                <?php endwhile; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                <?php $plus++; ?>

            <?php endforeach; ?>


            <?php

                $userEmail = $user->user_email;
                $userName = $user->first_name;
                $link = get_template_directory_uri();
                $eventhtml = '';

                $args = array(
                    'post__in' => $matchedEvents,
                    'post_type' => 'event'
                );


                $event_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                $plus = 0;

               $headers = 'From: What`s On Advisor <info@whatsonadvisor.com>' . "\r\n";
               $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
               $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
               $message = '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"><html><head><title>What`s On Advisor</title><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">';
               $message .= '<style type="text/css">* { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; } a { color: #61c7dd; text-decoration: none; } a:link {color: #61c7dd;} a:hover { color: #59b8cc; } hr { border: none; height: 2px; width: 100%; background: #767572; float: left; text-align: left; } </style>';
               $message .= '</head><body bgcolor="#0e72b0" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">';
               $message .= '<table width="600px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin:0 auto;"><tr><td valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff"><table width="600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font: 14px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #767572; line-height: 100%;"><tr><td colspan="3"><table width="600" height="120" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td valign="top" style="width: 600px; height: 125px; text-align: center;"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="height: 125px;"><tr><td style="height: 33px; background-color:rgb(44, 63, 79);"><img src="'.$link.'/img/email-logo.jpg" height="33" width="279" /></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr style="padding: 20px 10px;"><td valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="color: #767572; padding: 10px;"><tr><td style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 30px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; color: #767572; letter-spacing: -2px; line-height: 160%;">Hi '.$userName.',</td></tr><tr><td style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 130%; color: #767572;"><small>Here are a list of events that you have added to your planner. They are all starting within the next week so be sure to go along for a fun day out! Go back to your <a href="'.site_url().'/planner">planner</a> to edit events or use the <a href="'.site_url().'/search">search</a> to find more great events.</small></td></tr></table></td></tr>';

               $message .= '<tr style="padding: 20px 10px; width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                        <td valign="top" style="width:100%; display:block;"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="color: #767572; padding: 10px;">
                          <tr>
                            <td style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 130%; color: #767572;">';


                foreach( $event_query->posts as $post ) : ?>

                    <?php 
                        $eventlink = get_permalink();
                        $title = get_the_title();

                        $message .= '<tr>';
                        $message .= '<tr style="padding: 10px 10px 0px 10px; width: 100%; display:block;">';
                        $message .= '<h2><a href="'.$eventlink.'">'.$title.'</a></h2>';
                        $message .= '</tr>';

                    ?>


                        <?php if( have_rows('date') ): ?>

                            <?php $row = 0; ?>

                            <?php while ( have_rows('date') ) : the_row(); ?>
                                <?php $row++; ?>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>

                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php if( have_rows('date') ): ?>

                                <?php while ( have_rows('date') ) : the_row(); ?>


                                    <?php
                                        $startDate = get_sub_field('start-date');
                                        $newDate = date("m/d/Y", strtotime($startDate));
                                        $endDate = get_sub_field('end-date');
                                        $countdownDate = date("F j, Y ", strtotime($startDate));

                                        if( have_rows('start-end-times') ) : 
                                            while ( have_rows('start-end-times') ) : the_row();

                                                $startTime = get_sub_field('start-time');
                                                $newTime = date("G:i A", strtotime($startTime));
                                                $countdownTime = date("G:i:s", strtotime($startTime));

                                            endwhile;
                                        endif; 

                                        $countdownFormat = $countdownDate.' '.$countdownTime;
                                        $date = date('Ymd');
                                        $count = 1;
                                    ?>

                                    <?php if( $endDate < $date && $count === $row ) : ?>
                                            <?php $date = date("F j, Y", strtotime($startDate)); ?>
                                        <?php break; ?>

                                    <?php elseif ( $endDate > $date  ) : ?>

                                        <?php if( $startDate < $date ) : ?>
                                            <?php $date = date("F j, Y", strtotime($startDate)); ?>
                                            <?php $count++; if ($count >= 1) {
                                                break;
                                            } ?>

                                        <?php elseif ( $startDate > $date ) : ?>
                                                <?php $date = date("F j, Y", strtotime($startDate)); ?>
                                            <?php $count++; if ($count >= 1) {
                                                break;
                                            } ?>

                                        <?php endif; ?>

                                    <?php endif; ?>

                                <?php endwhile; ?>

                        <?php endif;

                        $message .= '<tr style="padding: 0px 10px; width: 100%; display: inline-block;">Starts: '.$date.'<br/></tr>';
                        $message .= '<tr style="padding: 0px 10px; width: 100%; display: inline-block;">Distance: '.$distance.'<br/><br/></tr>';

                        $description = get_field('mini-description');
                        $message .= '<tr style="padding: 20px 10px 20px; width: 100%; display: block;">'.$description.'<br/><br/></tr>';

                        $message .= '<tr>';
                        $plus++;

                endforeach;


               $message .= '</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr><br/><br/><br/>Thanks,<br/>What`s On Advisor<br /><br /><br /></tr>
                          <tr><small>If you`d like to unsubscribe from these e-mails, please login to <a href="'.site_url().'/account">your account</a> and change your preferences.</small></tr>
                        </table></td>
                      </tr>';

               $message .= '</table></td></tr>';
               $message .= '</table></body></html>';



               wp_mail($userEmail, 'Upcoming Events', $message, $headers );


               wp_reset_postdata();

            ?>





        <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php else : ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Why on earth are you putting PHP tags on almost every line?

Comment: Can you post some sample output? Expected vs returned.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure how to give you some sample output, as it's an e-mail? But essentially it returns the correct number of events, they're just all have the same information, when they should all be different.

Comment: There's a _lot_ going on in that code. Can you maybe strip it down a bit to a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that still exhibits the same behavior?